# Compute the percentage values with respect to 2 numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays of

```
arr1 = [ 1.32020091  1.22581158  1.1768816   1.1323538   1.14464306  1.08879001]
arr2 = [ 1.59808117  1.75764704  1.92353157  2.06407594  2.09463725  2.08504829]
```

where `arr1` and `arr2` are speed-ups values with respect to a base/reference implementation. What I want to calculate now is the percentage (contribution) of speed ups  coming from each `arr1` and `arr2`. Of course, I can do the following

```
print arr1/(arr1+arr2)*100
print arr2/(arr1+arr2)*100

[ 45.2389752   41.0869309   37.95886341  35.42558086  35.33633869  34.30515063]
[ 54.7610248   58.9130691   62.04113659  64.57441914  64.66366131  65.69484937]
```

But this is not correct, because if you look at the last value of `arr1` (`1.08879001`) and `arr2` (`2.08504829`), it says that `1.08879001` has very negligible contribution in speed-up whereas almost double the speed-up comes from `2.08504829`.

How can I compute the percentage contribution of each array? The contributions still need to add up to `100`

Comment: So what's the desired result, numerically, in your example?

Comment: sounds like you are taking percentages of percentages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `arr1` and `arr2` represent multiples, you just need to subtract `1` from each before doing the calculation:

```
print (arr1 - 1) / (arr1 + arr2 - 2) * 100
print (arr2 - 1) / (arr1 + arr2 - 2) * 100
```

In your example, this gives 7.6% and 92.4% for the last two values.

Comment: This does it. Fantastic!